# margin-bottom doesn't work

Tags: html, css, alignment, margin

I am trying to position a loading image in the buttom right of the page, but everything works fine except margin-bottom.

```
<div id="preload">
    <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:40px; margin-right:50px;">
        <img src="http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/loading.gif" alt="" />
        <br>
        <a style="color:#00ff24;"><b>Please wait while the page is loading...
        <br>If the website doesn't load within one minute please refresh your page!</b>                                                                                                 
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anybody tell me what or how to make it work?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign position absolute and use bottom and right proprietes.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yrUy/

```
<div id="preload">
<div align="right" style="position:absolute; bottom:40px; right:50px">
    <img src="http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/loading.gif" alt="" />
    <br><a style="color:#00ff24;"><b>Please wait while the page is loading...<br>If the website doesn't load within one minute please refresh your page!</b></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

It's the nature of margins vs padding.  Since margins sit outside of the element, they won't render unless there's another element following.  You could use bottom-padding of 1px on the parent; that should trigger the render.

Comment: I would do it like that too! Or even better, delete the margin on the inner element and add it as a padding to the outer element.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in the bottom right of the page just use this css:

```
.yourClass {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

If you want to change the amount of pixels change 0 to what you want

Answer (score 2):

try absolute position and use bottom/right instead of respective margins:

```
<img src="http://thc-racing.ucoz.com/design/loading.gif" alt=""  style="position: absolute; bottom:40px; right:50px;"/>
```

Here - http://jsfiddle.net/maximua/SKcvr/

Answer (score 2):

I had a case where I needed to add `display: inline-block`.

I can't explain why this worked, but it did! :-) Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Even when set `display:block` to parents and child divs, the margin bottom may not work. The best thing to solve this, after testing with paddings and big margin top values, is using `position:relative;` for the parent container, and `position:absolute;` for the child div. The div and other elements have already the display-block for default, so we don‘t need to declare it, as follows:

```
.parent{
position:relative;
height: 20rem;
/* A big value for height will help you to see the “margin-bottom” with clarity. */
}

.child{
position:absolute;
bottom:0.25rem;
/* or whatever measurement you want: 1rem, 1em, 15px, etc. Be AWARE that it‘s not “margin-bottom” property; it‘s just “bottom” within the absolute position. */
}
```

In the HTML just consider:

```
<header class="parent"> 
<p>This is your main container which has 20rem of height.</p>
<div class="child">
<p>This text is very close to the bottom.</p>
</div>
</header>
```

In the CSS I consider only the most relevant properties. You can add colors, backgrounds, font-families and so on, which will not affect the layout. I just coded the key properties to create the “effect margin-bottom”.

[Example more fancy.](https://codepen.io/limakid/pen/vYmZprp?editors=1100)